# Wordpress - how can I get rid of flicker?

Tags: wordpress, frontend, flicker

I have a problem with my website page. It used to be okay, but now when I load it in a private browser(Chrome), the page flickers. I tried minifying css, optimizing images..even changing the html structure, but it seems to always have some problem...any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question has little value to the community as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async-hide` class creating the issue with opacity property. Overwrite it by

```
.async-hide {
    opacity: 1!important;
}
```